# Фреймворки PHP

Tags: framework, php

Собственно, что такое фреймворк? Типа cakePHP? Как делаются фреймворки? Это просто набор вспомогательных классов и функций или что-то другое? Или новый язык, основанный на php?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- По сути, *фреймворк* - это набор вспомогательных классов и решений для каких-либо шаблонных задач. Из известных примеров - [`CakePHP`](http://cakephp.org/), [`CodeIgniter`](http://codeigniter.com/), [`Symfony`](http://www.symfony-project.org/), [`Kohana`](http://kohanaframework.org/).
- Фреймворки обычно рождаются, когда разработчика или группу разработчиков задалбливает делать одни и те же задачи заново и они понимают, что для решения этих схожих задач можно применять какие-либо **общие подходы**.  Эти "подходы" как раз и выносятся во фреймворк.

> В некоторых случаях фреймворки внутри себя реализуют так называемые `DSL` - `domain-specific language`, т.е некоторый новый простой язык программирования, предназначенный для решения узкоспециализированных задач. *При этом интерпретируется этот язык (в случае PHP-фреймворков), разумеется, с помощью внутренних средств `PHP`.*

Comment: Ну вот CakePHP ведь не просто набор классов, но и DSL.
А как реализуется DSL? Какие-то изменения делают в интерпретаторе?

Comment: @mctrane Ну в случае веб-разработки, каждый такой фреймворк нынче модно выпускать с шаблонизатором на борту, который и является DSL'ем. Я, естественно, не изучал исходный код `CakePHP`, но готов предположить, что есть некоторе ядро самого фреймворка, и, соответственно, есть некоторая часть данного ядра, которая интерпретирует и выполняет лексический разбор шаблонного кода. *А дальше, раз анализ проведен, то все остальное просто и уже можно отдавать готовые страницы.*

Comment: @mctrane Разумеется, в реальных фреймворках все намного сложнее, но, думаю, что общую картину я обрисовал правильно. Для такой реализации изменения в самом `php` не требуются, хотя, чисто теоретически, какой-либо функционал такого плана можно вынести в отдельные подключаемые модули интерпретатора. *Благо `php` не монолитен.*

Comment: А можно ли считать за фреймворк, несколько функций работы с формами?

Comment: @mctrane Ну это уж, простите, вопросы терминологии. Фреймворком можно и один класс без функций назвать, а потом ходить и говорить - вот, мол, я написал 1000 разных фреймворков.